# MySQL 5.7.32 on Ubuntu 18.04 - connections dropping even at localhost/command line

Tags: 18.04, server, mysql

I have a weird one I haven’t been able to find an answer for, posting here in case someone, somewhere has an idea:

Ubuntu 18.04 with MySQL 5.7.32 -
We are getting what seem to be random disconnects. This includes on localhost through the command line interface. Result after a pause at times is

`MySQL server has gone away`

We have increased `wait_timeout`, `interactive_timeout`, `max_allowed_packet`, etc. and none have had any effect. We’re using an older MyODBC driver, but have experimented with different versions and get the same result. The MyODBC `AutoReconnect` flag is on, but the connection still fails.

Note again that even on localhost we get the disconnect, so we are sure it’s not a network problem. It seems to be an issue with MySQL, but we have been unable to spot any setting out of place or that changing has had any effect.

Also note that we’ve seen what appears at times to be ‘groups’ of dropped connections - where 4-8 users will suddenly report a drop. This could be pertinent, or it could be coincidence or they may just not be reporting errors as consistently as we would like.

Anyway, grasping at straws here. Thank you.

Comment: Another possibilty I have seen (but not tried myself) is to increase `innodb_log_file_size = 128MB` or higher.

Comment: I will try that.  Interestingly, these tables started as MyISAM and were converted to InnoDB in the hope that it would eliminate the problem.

Comment: If multiple people are getting kicked off at the same time, this would point to a memory issue. Increasing the swap file size may resolve this.

Comment: So I increased the innodb_log_file_size as recommended and that didn't help.  As for memory, the system has 128GB with a 128GB swap file, and the swap file isn't being used.  Could there be a fault there I'm missing?  It SEEMS to only be happening to MySQL, but MySQL is by far and away the heaviest service on the system (also has SMB and FTP).